# Getting HTTP response code using Android Asynchronous Http Client (Loopj)

Tags: android, http, rest, loopj

I'm using loopj to talk to a rest server which has different HTTP response codes for specific successful responses (i.e 200, 202). The AsyncHttpResponseHandler has an onSuccess(String content) callback but nothing that returns the HTTP response code. How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@Override    
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, String content) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using an older version of the code which did not have this callback.

Comment: This method is now deprecated.